# VSC++ explicit initializer for arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

I've ported a C++ project from MinGW compiler to Visual Studio C++. I have a private attribute of a class:

```
bool hisStateTable[HIS_STATES][HIS_STATES] =
{   // the rows and cols represent the state for His: OFF, SAFE, Boot Boot Maintenance, Low Voltage Engineering, High Voltage Standby, Test Science, Normal Science, Burst Science
    { false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false }, // OFF state table
    { false, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, false },   // Safe state table
    { false, false, false, true, true, false, false, false, false },  // Boot state table
    { false, false, false, true, true, false, false, false, false },  // Boot_Maint state table
    { false, false, false, false, true, true, false, false, false },  // LV_Engin state table
    { false, false, false, false, true, true, true, true, false },    // HW_Sdby state table
    { false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false }, // Test_Sc state table
    { false, false, false, false, false, true, false, true, true },   // Normal_Sc state table
    { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false }  // Burst_Sc state table
};
```

But the following error appears when I compile it:

```
cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays
```

Comment: VS don't support this for struct/class members. initialize in the constructor. Or have it a non member.

Comment: If you don't mind sharing the same array amongst all your class instances (most likely in the case of a read-only array), then declare it `static` and write this initialization outside your class.

Comment: Normally I'd recommend using `std::array` here, but a quick test has cause VS2013 to raise an internal compiler error. Happy days.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax shown is valid C++. It's called *list-initialization* and is described in n3797 S8.5.4. It can be used in many different situations.

I have been unable to find specific mention of which kinds of arrays can be initialised this way. It can certainly be used for arrays declared at file scope and local arrays declared in a function. Perhaps someone more familiar with the standard can point out where the standard deals with *list-initialization* of non-static member arrays. Initialisation of class members is mentioned in S9.2. Perhaps the details have changed between versions of C++.

On the assumption that (at least for the compiler that you are using) this is not permitted, you have little choice but to initialise the array in a constructor. You could create a local variable and memcpy it over in the constructor, or you could do the same thing with an a static array declared at file scope.

```
static bool hisStateTable_static[HIS_STATES][HIS_STATES] = {
  // omitted
};

SomeClass::SomeClass(void) {
  assert(sizeof(hisStateTable_static) == sizeof(_state_table));
  memcpy(_state_table, hisStateTable_static, sizeof(_state_table));
}
```

This is the simplest code with fewest dependencies, not necessarily the best way to do it.

Please note that the compiler will check that you do not have too many initialisers, but if you have too few it will supply additional zeros.

Comment: Sorry about the previous poor quality answer. Hopefully this will serve better.